# How to get all the sentences in which a pos_tag pattern has been applied

Tags: python

I am obviously new to Python and I would like someone to help me perform the following task.

I have already got some sentences pos_tagged using spacy and textacy, as you can see here:

> 'sentence = 'Ela disse que tudo ficaria bem. Não podia ser assim. Ele afirmou que nada seria perdido. Não sabia se eles viriam. Ele relatou que não queria mais ficar em casa. Eles responderam que não tinha nada errado. A pessoa que foi ao bar não voltou. Nós acreditávamos que isso funcionaria. Ninguém que sabia isso foi embora.'

I had to apply `nlp = spacy.load('pt_core_news_md')` as I am working with the Portuguese language.

```
doc = nlp(sentence)

verbs = textacy.extract.matches.token_matches(doc, patterns=pattern,)
indireto_sentence = []

for verb in verbs:
    indireto_sentence.append(verb)
```

Then, I successfully got what I needed, so far so good:

```
verbs = textacy.extract.matches.token_matches(doc, patterns=pattern,)
indireto_sentence = []

for verb in verbs:
    indireto_sentence.append(verb)
print(indireto_sentence)
```

out:

```
[disse que,
 afirmou que,
 sabia se,
 relatou que,
 responderam que,
 acreditávamos que]
```

Fantastic! However, I want to get all the sentences in which these pos_tagged phases ("disse que", "afirmou que", "sabia se" etc) appear as they were in the `sentence`. In other words, I want to have the sentences to which I apllied the pos_tagg method.

The desired outcome would have to be like:

out:

> Ela disse que tudo ficaria bem. Ele afirmou que nada seria perdido. Não sabia se eles viriam. Ele relatou que não queria mais ficar em casa. Eles responderam que não tinha nada errado. Nós acreditávamos que isso funcionaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to loop over the sentences in the spacy doc and do a match on each sentence. Then just keep the sentences that have a match.

```
doc = nlp(sentence)
sentences_with_verbs = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    verbs = list(textacy.extract.matches.token_matches(sent, patterns=pattern))
    if len(verbs) > 0:
        sentences_with_verbs.append(sent)

print(sentences_with_verbs)
```

Comment: No problem, can you mark it as accepted if it works? That makes it clear the question has been answered. Which then makes it easier for others to find questions that still need answers.